# Timer not having output after initial powering

Tags: switches, relay, timer, output, timing

DGM TIMER RELAY BOARD 12V 1S-1HR
Time Delay ON or OFF 12V Relay Board with jumper settings and 8 Time Ranges selectable from 0.1s up to 1 hour accessing loads 250VAC 10A or 30VDC 10A
I believed this timer was supposed to operate for whatever duration is set by s1,s2 and s4 then stop for an hour then reenergizes again. Hence cycle of on/off continue but it is just running when powered on for the first time, then stops for good. Please assist is where I am going wrong in the settings??

Comment: Please include a copy of the manual in your question.

Comment: Please supply: Full brand model manual links.

Comment: As the others have pointed out, if you dont actually give enough information for anyone to find the datasheet then no one can help.